# When a row is deleted it is NOT Physically Deleted but marked deleted. Teradata

Tags: indexing, teradata, partitioning

I have been studding about columnar tables in Teradata. And came to know about "When a row is deleted it is NOT Physically Deleted but marked deleted." I am wounding is it just applied to only columnar tables or simple tables also? and Any logic behind doing so? Thanks.

Comment: Only for columnar tables, there's always an hidden additional/hidden partition storing a single bit per row. If a row was physically deleted it would no longer be possible to calculate the RowIDs of the following rows.

Comment: Then when actually a row get deleted?

Comment: Is additional/hidden partition like Row Reference Array?

Comment: A row is physically deleted when you submit either a delete without where-condition, i.e. truncating the table or when the where-condition matches all rows in a partititon